# what will happen if UDP sender send so much info that receiver can not receive?

Tags: udp

I guess that the receiver will just throw away message that it can not receive and the network will become congest because of too many message.But I do not know whether it is correct and hope someone could tell me more about other consequences.

Comment: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/udp-flood-ddos-attack/

Answer (score 0):

> I guess that the receiver will just throw away message that it can not receive ...

If the receiver is not able to handle the load of packets then they will be simply discarded. Since UDP has no inherent reliability layer and flow control as TCP does, neither the sender nor the receiver will notice that packet loss.  To detect this some kind of sequence number or similar would need to be added to the messages.

> ... the network will become congest because of too many message.

Just because the receiver is not able to handle the load, the network does not come congested. The packets will not be buffered somewhere in the network, they are simply lost. The network will only get congested if the number of packets fills the bandwidth of the network, not if a single receiver somewhere is not handle the load.

Not even the system with the receiver application itself need to be overloaded and also not the receiver application. The OS kernel will put the datagrams into the receivers socket buffer. If the buffer is full the packets get discarded. The buffer can be full not only if the application is not able to keep up with the sender but also if the receiver is doing other things and simply not trying to `recv` packets in the first place.

Comment: thank you very much,I have not get 15 reputation so I am not able to vote this answer.But  this answer help me.